# connecting mongoDB server on linux machine from windows machine

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a windows system through which I am connecting mongoDB server on amazon EC2 instance on linux machine. I am doing following in python

```
from pymongo import MongoClient  

client = MongoClient('ip here',27017)
```

But It says `raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))  ConnectionFailure: timed out`

I have added a rule in security groups in EC2 instance to allow all inbound conncetions on 27017 port.

Even I changed `bind_ip:0.0.0.0 from 127.0.0.1`  But still it gives me the same error. Please help

Comment: The correct thing should be MongoClient("mongodb://ip:27017"), and you don't have to change `bind_ip` you have to `comment it out` and then restart the mongoinstance on EC2

Comment: @NikhilParmar  Still it gives me the same error.

Comment: Try running `mongo ip:27017` on shell and let me know if it connects

Comment: @NikhilParmar   No its not getting connected. `exception : connect failed`

Comment: The only way to connect to mongo instance on EC2 is `commenting the bind_ip` and `restarting the mongo server`. You are doing wrong in one or the other

Comment: I did that but, still the same error. Do I have to make any changes in hosts file in linux?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102980/discussion-between-nikhil-parmar-and-neil).